# Need to disable and kill bouncy ball in a lab

Tags: centos-7, kde-plasma-5

I have a CentOS lab that doesn't yet have individual user accounts. Some students start the KDE app bouncy ball. I'd like a nice network, i.e., via CLI and Ansible, way to disable and kill all the bouncy balls.

I have root access. Currently, all the computers have one default "guest" account (without sudo access) and will soon be transferring to LDAP authentication.

This is a very popular topic but the solutions seem to be geared towards individual computers e.g. [here](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=106939) , [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=56723) , and [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1544529).

Comment: When you say it doesn't yet have individual user accounts, do you mean each computer is logged into using a single shared account? What rights does this account have? Do you retain root/admin for technical staff use only?

Comment: can you set the permissions on that app to be root only?

Comment: It's not a specific app. It's part of the desktop. Perhaps, I could set the desktop config file to read only but that carries some problems with it